# Should I say "sent by post" or "sent by a post"?

Tags: grammar, articles, indefinite-article

Should I use article "a" in this sentence?

> Has anyone sent documents by post

**or**

> Has anyone sent documents by **a** post?

Comment: "By post" sounds strange (maybe British) to me. In my dialect (US Midwest), I'd say "Has anyone mailed the documents?" or "Has anyone sent the documents by mail?"

Comment: @WaterMolecule:  To me (US, New England) it sounds a bit old-fashioned but not unintelligible.

Comment: @WaterMolecule "by post" is indeed perfectly normal in British English.

Comment: Yeah, "sent by **a** post" suggests that it was posted on Facebook or some such.

Comment: We use "by post" in India too. The word email has somehow transitioned into mail, so "by mail" here would refer to email. There's also epost which is a service from the Post Office that prints email delivers it by post.

Comment: "Has anyone sent documents by a post" to me sounds like you're asking if anyone has sent documents adjacent to a large wooden pole :)

Comment: The second version of this sentence "...by a post?" might be interpreted by a programmer as asking if anyone had uploaded documents using an HTTP POST request.

Comment: @JustinOhms Most people are not programmers and it annoys me that so many ELL questions get programmnig jargon answers.

Comment: Since this is today's simplest, most straight-forward question, let's have an incredibly long discussion about it  :)

Comment: @user253751  Correct most people are not programmers. Which is exactly why I left the comment. The fact that it is ancillary to the original intent of the OP is why I did not leave an answer. This is similar to the comment made by Hot Licks regarding Facebook posts. It is an extra detail to clarify to an ELL in what context they might hear the alternative form and meaning it might convey. Because in these contexts, it makes perfect sense. I can do nothing about you being annoyed with the fact that English has niche jargon and evolves over time. My comment was meant for those learning English.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

"Post" in this sense is an uncountable or mass noun (as noted by [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/post)), so you'd always say "by post" (or "in the post", "via post" or "by mail"), never "by a post".

Comment: I'm not sure that you could really call it uncountable in a strict sense, because there's only one postal system.

Comment: _Countabililty_, as it is being used here, is a grammatical property of words, not a description of entities in the phenomenal world. I've noticed before that pedants seem to have a remarkable inability to cope with polysemy.

Comment: I don't get it. There are multiple postal services available. "Postal service" is countable.

Comment: @Basilevs I don't think "post" and "postal service" are exact synonyms. Also, many countries have only one postal service in the true sense (offering delivery of letters to any address). But when discussing those with more than one, I don't think I would ever say "this country has several posts to choose from". However, even if one did decide, inventively, to use "post" as a countable noun in that way, deliveries would still be "by post". It's a mechanism, a means. The other answer rightly drew our attention to the parallel with "by rail".

Comment: @Basilevs: How are there multiple postal services?  There's only one, even if parts of it are run by different entities.  E.g. if I write a letter to my friend in Britain, and put it in my USPS mail box, it gets delivered.

Comment: @jamesqf and then there is citymail, Hermes, UPS, DPD and many others available for me to use. So there are quite a number of postal services competing with each other. And then there is the "post" also called "deutsche post"

Comment: @KamiKaze Lexico defines "postal service" as "US: post office (sense 1)", which in turn is defined as "The public department or corporation responsible for postal services and (in some countries) telecommunications".  Meanwhile, Brits tend to describe DHL, Hermes etc as parcel delivery services or courier services rather than postal services.  But regardless, these are separate points - they don't change the answer to the OP's question.

Comment: I'd say *the* postal service is USPS (in the USA) but FedEx, UPS, etc. are still postal services. UPS is "a" postal service (or "a" courier service). (But note my dialect is not American English).

Comment: IMHO, this sense of "post" is an abstract noun, not a mass noun. It refers to the general system that involves mailing physical documents.

Comment: Abstract/concrete is one dichotomy, mass/countable is another.  When we say "by rail" or "by truck", are we using "rail" and "truck" as mass nouns, or is there simply a rule that suppresses the article in this type of expression?  Regardless, there is an important difference, because "truck" can serve as countable noun, whereas "post" can't (except in other, clearly distinct meanings).  I can say "yesterday's post arrived late", but I can't say *"we had a late post yesterday".  I can say "he delivered the post today" but not *"he'll deliver another post tomorrow".

Comment: @Barmar / rjpond I stand corrected; of course if you need more than 1 truck to deliver something, you're still doing it "by truck". I'll retract my comment.

Comment: @rjpond Of course, these words have a number of different senses, and the mass/countable distinction only applies to some of them. The sense used after "by" is the abstract sense, so countability doesn't apply. Isn't language wonderful!

Comment: @Kami Kaze: At least in the US, services like UPS, FedEx, &c are parcel delivery services.  The distinction is a legal as well as a linguistic one: they can't legally deliver mail (post in British English), only packages (which might of course contain written documents), and can't put them in your mail box.  Though the USPS can deliver packages, and put them in your mail box...

Comment: @jamesqf I am not sure about UPS, DPD and Hermes (those might be parcel) , but in germany we have "Deutsche Post" the original postal service, "citymail" which is a distribution service for mail maintained by the city I think and "postcon" which is a private postal service. There might be more. So at least in germany "postal service" or its translation would be considered a general term and "Post" would refer to the original federal institution, that is now privaticed.

Answer (score 19):

No, *by* here shows the method in use, how the action of sending documents is done - by post. It's an uncountable noun which refers to [the public system for collecting and delivering of letters](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/post), so *a post* is never the case.

Similarly, you can travel by train/car, you can pay by cheque, you can carry/ship goods by sea/air, you can read by candlelight.

---

> We use **by + zero article** to talk about means of transport and communication, including
>
> - go/travel by car/taxi/bus/plane/train/air/sea
> - communicate/contact by phone/post/mail/email
>
> Compare:
>
> - I generally **go by bus** to work.
> - I generally **take the bus** to work.
>
> <sub>Source: Advanced Grammar in Use Third Edition by M Hewings</sub>

Comment: I agree. Just like you'd say "by email" and you would not imply one of the many providers.

Answer (score 9):

It is normal to say "by post" in British English (or "by mail" in American English).

You would never use an indefinite article with "post" in this context, since there is only one post ("a post" would therefore be a fence-post or similar). However, it can be correct to use a definite article, as in "through the post".